# Bugs in scroll-follow with Google map (Firefox and Safari)

Tags: css, firefox, google-maps, safari, scroll

A scroll follow effect is when a part of the web design is always visible, even when the window is scrolled.

There are animated and static versions of this.

The animated is ok http://robertomartinez.info/cobra/index.html

But I prefer the fixed version, however I have some bugs:
http://robertomartinez.info/cobra/index_fixed.html

-In Firefox, when you scroll the page, you will see a kind of vertical cut in the lorem ipsum text (below the HERE indication). This is caused by the image tiles of the map, then if you drag and drop the map, the cut will appear in another side.

-In Safari, when you scroll the page, the div follows, but the map images stay in the same position.

Do you have solutions for these issues? Thanks.

Comment: Although I notice the cut when scrolling in FF 3.6.3/Linux, the lagging part (indeed near HERE) is re-rendered almost immediately, so I cannot reproduce your issue here. BTW, no problem whatsoever in Chromium 5.0.375.55, so probably not a WebKit issue.

Comment: Chrome and IE8 are fine. 
What do you mean with "cannot reproduce your issue here"? On your localhost?

Comment: No, I don't see the effect you describe in the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

what versions of Firefox and Safari are affected? Also, have you tried experimenting with the iframe version of that map?